# How to fix 3D Acceleration for Vmware Workstation 9?

Tags: virtualization, opengl

I have recently installed Vmware workstation 9 on Ubuntu 12.04  & i have migrated my VM's from windows to Ubuntu 12.04 . Now i am getting openGL error & it says no 3D acceleration as shown in pic below

[image]

> How Do I Fix It ?

Comment: What graphics drivers do you have? What graphics card? 'twould be helpful to give a specific model.

Comment: Intel HD 3000 , Nvidia Optimus ....  By the way it was working fine  in windows 7 .

Comment: Optimus/hybrid is still under heavy development.  Watch https://launchpad.net/~hybrid-graphics-linux for developments

Comment: Did you install drivers for it?

Comment: yes bumblebee is installed ...

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Add the following to the .vmx file of the VM

```
mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = "TRUE"
```

Next, install the `Mesa-libtxc_dxtn1` (aka the S3 texture compression), this will probably called something be different since you are on Ubuntu and I'm using OpenSUSE 12.2.

Chances are this will crash your VM like it does to mine and only a reboot will fix it. Trying `nomodeset` from the boot-loader then uses the Nvidia graphics (I think - my CPU usage still rockets with `glxspheres`) which then WON'T crash your VM.

FYI - I have tried this but I'm afraid 3D acceleration support with Bumblebee is totally shite on Linux.

Comment: I was having problems with VMware Workstation 9.0.0 not working after i updated the kernel to 3.5, on ubuntu 12.04. Then i uninstalled and installed version 9.0.1, and added the above line to my WinXP VMX file, and now i get  full 3D support. Actually just tested Win 8, and Aero Glass is working as well. I have Intel HD 3000 VGA by the way.

Comment: I have a system76 laptop with on board Intel graphics 4000 and was getting this error.  Added the line gave me a warning, but it worked...just tested directX 3D support.

Comment: I have also found that 3d does not work for shared VM. Make sure it is not shared !!!!!

Comment: This helped even with my ATI Mobility 3650 on Ubuntu 13.10.

Comment: TRUE should be in double quotes

Comment: +1. `Intel HD 4000`, `Kali` (`Debian 7`), `VMware 10`

Comment: I submitted an edit for the quotes.  The associated Ubunutu/Mint package is named: libtxc-dxtn-*  I had to disable multi-core to make this work also.

Comment: +1. Works for Intel HD3000 on kubuntu 12.04 with VMWare Player 6.  The mesa library package is called "libtxc-dxtn-s2tc0" on kubuntu 12.04.

Comment: In Ubuntu 14.04, `sudo apt-get install libtxc-dxtn*` worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> Installing Intel Driver Fixed Vmware 3D Acceleration
>   https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads
>
> Also install VA-API (Hardware Acceleration For Intel / AMD GPUs) 
>   [Is there a power saving application similar to Jupiter?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681)

No need to do any tweaks

Comment: Unfortunately, Intel(R) Linux* Graphics Installer for Ubuntu 12.04 is obsolete and Intel doesn't provide download link for that release in the page anymore. I then decided to install the driver from x-updates PPA ( https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=5452-IOSM-1474&l=english ), but the error messages persisted. I then added mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = "TRUE" to the .vmx file and it now works. :)

Comment: @Inoe ...There is noting extra added in intel drivers ...only VA-API ....check my answer Intel Hardware Acceleration http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681 .. install it

Comment: New version became available recently: http://askubuntu.com/a/850431/151837

Answer (score 2):

@Xxx Xxx

I think you're wrong. If your virtual machines works without errors ("Hardware graphics acceleration is not available", "No 3D support is available from the host"), it may be because you have activated the "mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = TRUE" option in your vmx configuration file. If so, your virtual machines will explode shortly after boot. Try a game and see.

Many have tried the solution you propose and none of them works. Check out this thread:
http://communities.vmware.com/message/2104179#2104179

Moreover, if you see there errors, YOU DO NOT HAVE graphics acceleration active in VMs.

Note: with Bumblebee (optirun vmware) you do not have graphics acceleration.

Comment: i have posted there as well ..... no aero in windows 7 .... mean no 3D accelration

Comment: mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = TRUE worked for me. although, before I tried this, I found the following page on the ubuntu forums, tried that, and it didn't work. Is it possible that both of these things together creates a fix?
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1531911

Comment: Actually, this does work for me (Running Altium Designer in a Windows 7 32-bit guest, on a 64-bit Ubuntu 13.04 host, with VMWare Player 6.0.0).