# Cannot get 3D OpenGL support in Vmware guests, how can I fix this?

Tags: intel-graphics, vmware, opengl

I have been working at this problem for 2 days now. I cannot for the life of me enable 3D support in VMWare 9 guests.

My specifications are:

> Hardware: Dell Latitude E5520 laptop.
>   Processor: Intel i7-2620M CPU @ 2.70GHz × 4.
>   Memory: 8GB.
>   Video: Intel Sandybridge Mobile x86/MMX/SSE2
>   OS: Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS, 32 bit.
>   Vmware Workstation: 9.0.1 build-894247
>   Glxgears functions fine. Frame rate is ~60fps.
>   Vmware guest: Windows 7

Starting the Windows 7 guest in VMware throws the following errors:

1. `No 3D support is available from the host.` and
2. `Hardware graphics acceleration is not available.`

I've [read through this VMware forum thread](http://communities.vmware.com/message/2104179#2104179), but again the hardware in the post is different (nVidia).

I've followed the instructions [at this Ask Ubuntu post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181829/how-to-fix-3d-acceleration-for-vmware-workstation-9) as closely as possible as the question is nearly the same as mine although my hardware is different.

[Answer 1](https://askubuntu.com/a/184385/78161) regarding setting `mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = TRUE`; in my `vmx` configuration file causes the VM to crash when it starts.

The [second answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/194268/78161) I followed as closely as possible.

- I uninstalled VMware,
- Did `sudo apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-$(uname -r)` at a terminal,
- Added the PPA `https://launchpad.net/~glasen/+archive/intel-driver`,
- Then at a terminal did `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade -y`

I reinstalled VMware and have the same results: no 3D in guests.

I'm getting the feeling that something is awry with the Sandy Bridge driver, but I can't seem to come up with any solutions. Has anyone out there run across this problem also?

By the way, the operation of the likes of Solidworks and AutoCad within a Windpws 7 guest does appear to be improved in VMware 9 vs VMware 8 in spite of the fact that 3D support is lacking in the Windows 7 guest.

I'd also add that my glxinfo file was nearly identical to the glxinfo file posted at askubuntu.com/questions/181829/…. I had a total of seven minor differences per a comparison using Meld. –

Comment: I'd also add that my glxinfo file was nearly identical to the glxinfo file posted at http://askubuntu.com/questions/181829/how-to-fix-3d-acceleration-for-vmware-workstation-9. I had a total of seven minor differences per a comparison using Meld.

Answer (score 2):

Probably bubmp, this worked to me on debian 8:
[How to fix 3D Acceleration for Vmware Workstation 9?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/181829/how-to-fix-3d-acceleration-for-vmware-workstation-9)

About mesa part: I installed:
`apt-get install mesa-utils`

Then I've checked OpenGL support in xserver.

```
user@linux:~$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Haswell Desktop
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.3.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 10.3.2
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.0
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

Then I added: `mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = "TRUE"` to end of *.vmx file.
This worked for Windows 8 and Windows 7 VMs.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem maybe these suggestions I've dug up from other threads will work for you.

I've run the intel-linux-graphics-installer updated my drivers. 
I've installed DRI and enabled S3TS Texture Compression.(solved problem on Ubuntu 12.04 machines) 
I've looked for fixes on multiple posts. I wish I understood exactly what was going on and I'd fix it but I don't know what else to do to enable 3D acceleration. I do have 640x480 and it does run.

VMWare 9.0.2 build-1031769 Ubuntu 13.04 Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T7800 @ 2.60GHz × 2 Intel® 965GM x86/MMX/SSE2
My thread:
[Enabling 3D acceleration VMware 9 Ubuntu 13.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/330797/182870)