# Enabling 3D acceleration VMware 9 Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: vmware

- I've run the intel-linux-graphics-installer updated my drivers.
- I've installed DRI and enabled S3TS Texture Compression. (solved problem on Ubuntu 12.04 machines)
- I've looked for fixes on multiple posts.

I wish I understood exactly what was going on and I'd fix it, but I don't know what else to do to enable 3D acceleration. I do have 640x480 and it does run.

- VMWare 9.0.2 build-1031769
- Ubuntu 13.04
- Intel® Core™2 Duo CPU T7800 @ 2.60GHz × 2
- Intel® 965GM x86/MMX/SSE2

Comment: Over 900 views. :( Sorry, no solution yet, hopefully we can figure this out

Comment: What a shame we can't run Ubuntu/Kubuntu properly on VMware anymore. I hope we don't need to build the driver our selves http://www.mesa3d.org/vmware-guest.html

Comment: I am using an Kubuntu x86 12.04 with VMware 8/9/10 without any problems: full 3D on KDE (eg Cube desktop effects that put Windows to shame). On the same machine Kubuntu/Ubuntu x86/x64 14.04 fail miserably...

Answer (score 3):

Open the VMX file:

```
vim winxp.vmx
```

And add these to the end:

```
mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = TRUE
```

try to boot the machine with 3D enabled.