# VMware and 3D acceleration

Tags: graphics, video, vmware, 3d

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 and then VMware 10.0.2 with Windows 7 as guest. I get `No 3D Acceleration` error when starting the guest machine. I have installed OpenGL and all Mesa lib files. Below is a display of my installation:

```
firmtechnologies@FirmTechnologies:~$ glxinfo | grep rendering
direct rendering: Yes
firmtechnologies@FirmTechnologies:~$ /usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p
OpenGL vendor string:   Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Sandybridge Mobile 
OpenGL version string:  3.0 Mesa 10.1.3

Not software rendered:    yes
Not blacklisted:          yes
GLX fbconfig:             yes
GLX texture from pixmap:  yes
GL npot or rect textures: yes
GL vertex program:        yes
GL fragment program:      yes
GL vertex buffer object:  yes
GL framebuffer object:    yes
GL version is 1.4+:       yes

Unity 3D supported:       yes
firmtechnologies@FirmTechnologies:~$ 

mks.gl.allowBlacklistedDrivers = "TRUE"  Added to .vmx file
```

but, I still get an error when trying to use the Windows Aero theme and other graphics display like running YouCam. What do I do?

Comment: Did you turn on 3D graphics in the vmware settings? VM settings -> Display -> Accelerate 3D graphics?

Comment: the Accelerate 3D graphics box is checked.

Comment: the Accelerate 3D graphics box is checked. The radio button "Use host settings for monitors" is selected as well

Comment: Take a look at http://askubuntu.com/questions/181829/how-to-fix-3d-acceleration-for-vmware-workstation-9

Comment: Thanks. I finally get it to work. really funny how stuffs work in Linux, but it is the best OS for me so far.