# No OpenGL support in video driver

Tags: 16.04, vmware, c++, opengl, sdl

I am working on an SDL2.0 library on my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop inside VMware and came across an error today that I cannot fix. It took me a bit to find it. I ended up just going through the code and print out `SDL_GetError()`'s. The first error that I encountered when printing this was `No OpenGL support in video driver`. I researched the error and haven't found any solutions yet. One post I read had the user post the output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` which for me returned

```
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: Gallium 0.4 on SVGA3D; build: RELEASE;  LLVM;
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 12.0.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.0 Mesa 12.0.6
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.00
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

I wasn't able to get much past that and don't really know what that output means, so here I am. Please note that I searched Google/askubuntu/stackoverflow and found little help. Most of the posts that I found were not related to my situation (I found it hard to believe). The closest result I got was on GitHub on some opensource project and the remedies that were offered were over my head. They also seemed to be specific to the specific GitHub project the person was having issues with

Also, I am testing my little project on my Surface Pro 4 as well and am having no such issues that I'm having here. I'm not sure if it's the way I installed it on the system (through mercurial) or if there is something additional wrong

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to fix 3D Acceleration for Vmware Workstation 9?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/181829/how-to-fix-3d-acceleration-for-vmware-workstation-9)

Answer (score 0):

I got this type of error one time because I had taken the KDE Window handler out. I put it back in and everything worked fine.

I am not sure if that is the problem here i just mention it as a place to start looking.

Comment: How do I do that? I don't know what that means

Comment: There is a command to shutdown lightdm [systemctl disable lightdm.service]. When I did that I could no longer run SDL 2.0. Once I left it alone then SDL worked fine. It has something to do with the windowing of SDL. I am not sure what happens if you use full screen.